# Google Play staged rollout

Tags: android, google-play-console

App version is v2, rollout is set to 10%.

- Is it possible for me as a developer/tester to download this **v2** version of the app from google play store if my account is not falling into **10% of the users which should see/receive update**?
  I've tried adding my account into **open/internal focus group** and even though i see that i'm beta tester on google play store, when i'm trying to install the app, **i see the v1 version of the app installed**.

**tldr**: I don't see a way in which i can download the latest app version from play store, **if it's a staged rollout and my account doesn't fall into rollout group.**

edit. I've uploaded **apk directly into production**, ignoring open testing/internal channels in google play console.